# Update Hashmap in background service

Tags: java, android, service, hashmap

I have a background service to track users location. In the service, I have a hashmap with Integer key and LatLng value. The service compares the user's location with the LatLng values. My problem is that sometimes I need to add another value to the hashmap.

I've tried 2 things.

1. I use https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk for sharedpref storage where I store this hashmap. When the hashmap is updated I save it to Hawk and then as the user's location changes I get the hashmap from the Hawk storage. Problem is that it returns the hashmap without the new value. The only time it actually gives the hashmap with updated value is if I restart the app.
2. I make the hashmap a static global variable in the Service so I can just update it in the service any time I need. In this case, the hashmap doesn't get updated at all.

So what's the best way for me to update the hashmap in my service?

EDIT Here's my Service Code -

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "LOCATIONTEST";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;
public static HashMap<Integer, LatLng> mLocationList;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
{
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
        // DO stuff here with update mLocationList HashMap

        // This should be the update list
        mLocationList = Hawk.get("LocationHashmap");

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    mLocationList =Hawk.get("LocationHashmap", new HashMap<Integer, LatLng>());
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}


}
```

In another Fragment the list is updated by first retreiving it from local storage then updating the list then saving it again.

```
    HashMap<Integer, LatLng> locationList = Hawk.get("LocationList");
    locationList.put(order.getId(), latLng);
    Hawk.put("LocationList", locationList;
```

Now, when OnLocationChanged is called I try to call Hawk.get("LocationList") to get the updated hashmap but it's not updated. I think there is something wrong with the library but I'm not sure what else to do. I've also tried making the list in the service static and just updating that list. So instead of the code above in the Fragment it would look like this:

```
LocationService.mLocationList.put(order.getId(), latLng)
```

But again the list isn't updated.

In OnCreate I get the HashMap from local storage. Say that list size is 2. Elsewhere in the app I update that list, now the list size is 3. Now when the service hits onLocationChanged I want to iterate through all of the values in the hashmap. But if I tried that same get from local storage to get the update hashmap the size is still 2. How can i update that hashmap in the service?

Comment: "sometimes I need to add another value to the hashmap" - I'm not sure I can follow, can you elaborate? Also please elaborate on the 2 things you tried, e.g. some code. I don't know Hawk and I'm no Android expert but I could at least try to comment on option 2. Btw static global variables hint at some misdesign, you might want to think about some better suited store such as redis/memcached or a database (I don't know whether the values need to be persistent).

Comment: Does Android JDK has `ConcurrentHashMap`? If yes you can use it

Comment: Post your code relevant to assigning values and storing/restoring your map.

Comment: Where exactly are you putting keys and values into the `HashMap`?

Comment: @Darwind in my UI Fragment

Comment: Ok, as @PM77-1 asks, please add the relevant code where you're storing/restoring your map.

Comment: @Darwind  I get the hashmap from local storage, update it, then save again. Then, every time onLocationChanged is called I call Hawk.get("LocationHashmap") to retrieve the updated hashmap. But the hashmap is not updated unless I restart the app. I've also tried making the hashmap static and just updating it that way. I'll edit my question to show some of this code.